# Ignore $MinPrecision when using Print

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, output

I have a function that contains a `For` loop and sometimes takes several hours to run. It's important that I keep a high precision, and I insert `Print` statements throughout to check the status. Here is a simplified example:

```
f[x_] := Block[{$MinPrecision = 500},
    For[i = 0, i < x, i++;
        y = i/2;
        Print[N[y, 10]]
    ];
];
```

Is there a way to ignore or suppress `$MinPrecision` when `Print` is used? I'd like to make the printed output easier to read.

Comment: Use NumberForm[y, 10]

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.